# HTML2PDF image tag stops rendering

Tags: html2pdf

I am playing around with HTML2PDF; I see a lot of questions about images not loading in the PDF, but cannot find a solution on how to resolve this. I have a very basic page I am playing with. I believe I have the page rendering the image now, but it just stops part way through with no errors. If I remove the image tag; the function works; but if I leave it in, it breaks. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://raw.githack.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/master/dist/html2pdf.bundle.min.js" defer></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body align="center">
        <div id="view" align="center">
            <h1>Export PDF</h1>
            <h3>Using HTML2PDF</h3>
            
            <img src="System24-7Logo.jpeg"/>
        </div>
        <button id="export-pdf">Export PDF</button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const exportPDF = document.getElementById("export-pdf")
        const element = document.getElementById("view");
        const opt = {
          filename: 'myPage.pdf',
          margin: 2,
          image: {type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.5},
          jsPDF: {format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait'}
        };
        // New Promise-based usage:
        exportPDF.onclick = (e) => html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();

    </script>
</html>
```

Console Log when clicking on Export button:

0ms html2canvas: html2canvas $npm_package_version
72ms html2canvas: Canvas renderer initialized (801x226 at 75.0625,0) with scale 1

Comment: did you find any solution ? because I am getting same issue

Comment: I had to move onto other projects; so I had put this on the back burner when I received no responses from anyone. I will attempt to work on this again in the future when I have more time. If I find a solution, I will post again here.